# PDFBox not keeping page subclass

Tags: java, pdfbox

This seems strange.  I am using PDFBox 3.  I am trying to use a subclass of page so I can add layout functions to it.

When I add a page of my subclass to a document and try to get it back, I am getting back a PDPage instance and not my subclass instance.

Here is a simple subclass:

```
package pdfBox;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

public class MyPage extends PDPage {
}
```

Here is a piece of test code:

```
package pdfBox;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

public class PageTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    doc.addPage(new MyPage());
    MyPage myPage = (MyPage)doc.getPage(0);
  }
}
```

I am getting this exception when I try to cast the page:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage cannot be cast to class pdfBox.MyPage
```

Any ideas why PDFBox would not keep a subclass?

Comment: Have a look at the source of PDPageTree.add

Comment: The PDPage objects aren't cached. A new one is created each time from the COSDictionary structure. It's your object, so keep it yourself.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr please add this as an answer so I can accept it.  Thank you.

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks for the info.  It looks like there is a member COSObject which is saved and then the page object is discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDPage objects aren't cached. A new one is created each time from the COSDictionary structure. It's your object, so keep it yourself.